# Pseudo elements transition

Tags: css, transition, opacity, pseudo-element

If you hover the element, the transition works, but not when you leave the element. How can I fix it?

This is my code and my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn5hdn45/)

```css
.block{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.fr:hover{
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    position: relative; 
 border-top: 2px solid rgba(150, 200, 200, 1); 
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
} 

.fr:before, .fr:after {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(150, 200, 200, 1) 0%, rgba(10, 20, 20, 1) 80%),    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(150, 200, 200, 1) 10%, rgba(10, 20, 20, 1) 100%);
    opacity: 0;
} 

.fr:hover:before, .fr:hover:after {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;  
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 200, 200, 1) 0%, rgba(10, 20, 20, 1) 80%),    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 200, 200, 1) 10%, rgba(10, 20, 20, 1) 100%);
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 2px; 
    opacity: 1;
} 

.fr:before { left: -2px; } 
.fr:after { right: -2px; }
```

```html
<div class="block fr"></div>
```

Comment: Move the `transition` properties out of `:hover` selectors, and onto `.block` or `.fr`.

Comment: Hello Sampson,thank you for your response.It works for the top and bottom bar,but not for the pseudo elements (left and right bars).

Comment: Can you show me what the begin, and end states should look like?

Comment: Just like in the demo,the problem is the smooth transition doesn't work in the pseudo elements when I unhover the element.

Comment: Try moving `position: relative` out of `:hover`, and place it on `.block` as well. While I'm not entirely sure what effect you're looking to achieve, jumping between `static` and `relative` could create issues. Also, move your `top`, `bottom`, and `width` properties out of the `:hover` state and onto the simple `::before` and `::after` selectors: https://jsfiddle.net/vn5hdn45/2/

Comment: That's what i want!Thank you so much for your time Sampson.

Comment: I've provided a more thorough answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous things needs to be done here. First, you need to apply transitions to the `.block .fr` element at all times (so it works on mouse-in, and mouse-out). Right now you're only applying transitions during the `:hover` state:

```
.block {
    /* Add `transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;` */
    /* Add `position: relative;` */
}

.fr:hover {
    /* Remove `position: relative;` */
    /* Remove `transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;` */
}
```

This allows the over-effect to fade in, and out. There is still an issue with the pseudo elements - they snap in and out of states, rather than transition. This is due to the presence of positioning properties (`top`, `bottom`, etc) on the `:hover` state, but not on the *static* state:

```
.fr:before, .fr:after {
    /* Add `top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 2px;` */
} 

.fr:hover:before, .fr:hover:after {
    /* Remove `transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;` */
    /* Redundant: `content: "";` */
    /* Redundant: `position: absolute;` */
    /* Redundant: `background-image: ...; */
    /* Remove `top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 2px;` */
}
```

When all is said and done, here's (roughly) what you're left with: https://jsfiddle.net/vn5hdn45/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the transition on the element before the hover so it transitions back into its original state.

```
.fr{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```